# Ruby 'initialize' no such file or directory error

Tags: ruby

I get "'initialize' no such file or directory error" when I try to run the following code:
(taken from 'Learn Ruby The Hard Way')

```
#Code start
filename=ARGV.first

txt=File.open(filename)

puts "Here is your file: #{filename}"

puts txt.read()

puts "Type it again"

file_again=STDIN.gets.chomp()

txt_again=File.open(file_again)

puts txt_again.read()

#Code end
```

Both of the ruby file and the txt file are in the same directory, even then it gives the error.

This is the error I get in cmd:

```
fileread.rb ex.txt

Here is your file: ex.txt

type it again

hello world

C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/fileread.rb:8:in `initialize': No such f
ile or directory - hello world (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/fileread.rb:8:in `open'
        from C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/fileread.rb:8:in main
```

Comment: You quite literally did not type your filename again, so how do you expect this to be correct?

Comment: Where do I need to type it again?

Comment: I mean, the program asks you to `type it again`? What did you think `it` meant?

Comment: Ah! sorry for asking such a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to type `ex.txt` when it asks you to type it again.